Why does pygame zero not work on python 3.13, but works on 3.12?
I am trying to build a game with Pygame Zero on the latest python release (3.13), but it can't find the module, so I have to use 3.12. Why is this? My code is here:
import pgzrun
from pgzhelper import *

pgzrun.go()

and i get
Import "pgzrun" could not be resolved
Please help! It would be appreciated

Did you try to install the module? (if so, please [edit] your post and talk about that. Don't explain what you did in comments)
